# 301 Redirecting old site to a new one while keeping same hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to 301 redirect my old site to the new one. I want to redirect all pages from the old site to the new site homepage, expect all pages belonging to this category

```
i.e. olddomain.com/articles/1 should be redirected to newdomain.com/articles/1
     olddomain.com/articles/2 should be redirected to newdomain.com/articles/2
     olddomain.com/articles/3 should be redirected to newdomain.com/articles/3
```

So generally, what I'm looking to do is:

1. redirect www and non-www version old site to the new one
2. Redirect all pages from old site to new site homepage all pages belonging to this category /articles

This is what I've done so far, but I'm not sure how to do the 2nd part.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/wp-admin/
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
 RewriteEngine on
#redirect /category/foobar to newdomain.com/category/foobar
 RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/categor/$1  [L,R=301]
#redirect everything else (except /wp-admin)  to the root of new domain
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
 RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```